# Way to hide all fixmes in latex document

Tags: comments, notes, fixme

I'm using the fixme package for a paper.

Is there a way to produce a PDF without any fixmes? This paper has a lot of fixmes, so I can't go enclosing each one in a `comment` or adding a `flag` that I check around each.

I tried adding the `final` option to `usepackage`, but that reports an error because the paper contains fatal fixmes.

Comment: try `\fxsetup{nopdfnote,nopdfmargin}`.

Comment: Thanks. This did not work: `Package xkeyval Error: `nopdfnote' undefined in families `mode,status,lang,lo
g,note,face,layout,envlayout,targetlayout,theme'.`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily redefine `\fxfatal` to do nothing, but this is against the purpose of that command and the `fixme` package.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{fixme}
\def\fxfatal#1{}
\begin{document}
Hello guis
\fxnote{Hi}, 
\fxwarning{Your supervisors are not "guys"} 
\fxerror{There are not address}
\fxfatal{Mispelled!!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one wonders if OP has read doc. By the way it says there that `\fixme` is deprecated, so perhaps OP is using `\fixme` which is now interpreted automatically as `\fxfatal`? then the answer could be to redefine `\fixme` rather to be `\fxerror` for example. Under final option (default) document will be built.